# Woocommerce additional price (woocommerce_before_calculate_totals) is not adding during payment

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In my application there is need to add extra price to each product if customer wants certain services, so I have added price from session (the extra price ) to each product by using woocommerce_before_calculate_totals hook,It works fine, whenever the total is showing including my extra price.

But the extra price is not added while making payment, only the product original price is sent to payment gateway, other wise in all places like (cart / checkout the right amount is showing)

Is there any hook that I am missing for payment where the extra price is not added.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which payment gateway?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following hook `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees`.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
  global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $percentage = 0.01;
    $surcharge = ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total ) * $percentage;    
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Surcharge', $surcharge, true, '' );

}
```

For reference: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/add-a-surcharge-to-cart-and-checkout-uses-fees-api/

add_fee reference: http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_cartadd_fee/